# appstore approval process iOS4 versus 3.2

Tags: iphone

My app is ready for OS 3.2, will Apple technically approve my application even if it's not ready for iOS4 ?

Answer (score 1):

No-one can say for sure. Apple have been so inconsistent with app approvals.

iPhone OS 3.2 is intended for iPad only - is your app an iPad app only, or universal?

If its a universal app, then it should be ready for both iPhone OS 3.1.3 and 3.2, and in which case should work without problems on iOS 4 (but you're going to have to test it on iOS 4 anyway).

If for some reason your app crashes on iOS 4or otherwise doesn't work as described, there's a good chance that Apple will reject it.

iOS 4 is released today, so Apple will be making a lot of effort to make sure apps work with it and if an app doesn't work, maybe remove it from the store and tell the developer to make it work.